# openURL not opening safari to from app

Tags: ios, safari, uiapplication

I have to clarify that I know how to open url from our iOS app, like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress]];
```

In my code I have done the same. It is an old app and I have to upgrade this app right now. I'm working on Xcode 7 right now. It has a code to open my website from the app. For that I have coded below for my website. I have also tried fro all other main site url but it still not opening safari to open this page.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        NSLog(@"OK");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open url: http://www.google.com");
    }
```

I have printed it that it goes in condition `canOpenURL:url` and it prints `OK` but it will not redirect to safari. I have checked in simulator and also in device but the result is same. Please help. Thanks in advance.

==== EDIT =======

This may be helpful more information about app.

It is tabbarcontroller app and navigation bar is shown for all views.

The above code is in button action

```
-(IBAction)onSiteClick:(id)sender
{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            NSLog(@"OK");
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open url: http://www.google.com");
        }
}
```

If I put this code in app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method then it open safari and works. But it is not working on button click. Even I have tried code in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`, then also it is not working.

===== EDIT 1  ====

I have not found solution for this yet. So for now I have taken a web view inside app and open the link in app.

Comment: http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes

Comment: @Max your code is working fine for me ..Hope may be the issue is with your website url string?

Comment: @Sujania Thats why I confused a lot. Because I have used this code for so many apps and I have also updated some apps with setting of LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and NSAppTransportSecurity to allow http connections.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new security feature of iOS 9. you need to add url in plist.

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>http://www.google.com</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I have tried that but still same Problem. And I think it is for custom url to open another app from our app.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
     <!--Include to allow all connections -->
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
     </dict>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the code is working fine in Xcode 7, iOS 9.0 ,os x 10.11

So, I think no issue with security.